# Textbooks on higher category theory

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, book-recommendation, higher-category-theory

What textbooks on [higher category theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/higher+category+theory) are there? What books do you recommend? I am looking for self-contained introductions, no research reports. There are lots of informal summaries and arXiv papers, but I am really only asking for textbooks here.

I know of Lurie's *[Higher Topos Theory](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/)*, which "only" treats $(\infty,1)$-categories. I am looking for books which treat $\infty$-categories in general. Then I know of Leinster's *[Higher Operads, Higher Categories](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~tl/hohc/)*, which is from 2004. Is it still up to date? Is Leinster's book the best introduction to the subject? What do you think of *[Higher-Dimensional Categories: an illustrated guide book](http://cheng.staff.shef.ac.uk/guidebook/)* by Cheng and Lauda, which is also from 2004 and still a draft? Is it too informal when one really wants to work with the concepts?

Bonus question: Meanwhile, is there some "preferred" definition of an $\infty$-category among the dozen definitions which have been studied?

Comment: The question is far from being settled. That is why there are no textbooks.

Comment: There *are* three textbooks, at least, and my question is in particular if someone has some experience with them.

Comment: Lurie's book is a textbook, but as you say, it not a textbook on $\infty$-categories. Leinster's book is not a textbook on $\infty$-categories in the same sense that CWM is a textbook on categories – you won't even find a higher Yoneda lemma in there. The same goes for the book of Cheng and Lauda.

Comment: Re: bonus question, a first answer it probably depends on who you ask. Sometimes people even use multiple models in a single paper -- recently I was at a talk where quasi-categories *and* complete Segal spaces were used (plus a brand new model based on striation sheaves). A second answer is that as far as I've noticed, there are a lot of attempts to try to make every argument model-independent. (Unrelated: there's also *Higher Algebra* by Lurie, but I don't know what qualifies as a textbook?)

Comment: Part IV of Riehl's book *Categorical Homotopy Theory*, "Quasi-categories", is sizeable, too.

Comment: I think Carlos Simpson's book [Homotopy theory of higher categories](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Homotopy+Theory+of+Higher+Categories) also deserves to be mentioned, even if it is not exactly what you are looking for.  It describes an approach to $(\infty,n)$-categories.  I do have to wonder what your motivation for studying $(\infty,\infty)$-categories is.

Comment: Again I wonder why answers are written as comments ...

Comment: Nobody mentioned Cisinski's Higher Categories and Homotopical Algebra, which I am reading right now as a beginner and finding very helpful and clear.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**1.**
First of all, make sure to have a few references on category theory available. Good ones include:

- [Basic Category Theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf) (Tom Leinster);
- [Category Theory in Context](http://www.math.jhu.edu/%7Eeriehl/context.pdf) (Emily Riehl);
- The [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/).

**2.**
It also pays of to learn about the insights leading to $\infty$-categories before learning about their theory proper. A good reference here is John Baez's [An Introduction to $n$-Categories](https://arxiv.org/pdf/q-alg/9705009.pdf). Another one is Section 1.2 of [Hellstrøm-Finnsen's thesis](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/cab6/eb68f1f71104baed0b374d392ffb6e7f398c.pdf).

**3.**
$\infty$-Categories require two fundamental prerequisites: model category theory and simplicial sets.

*Simplicial Sets.* Friedman's [An elementary illustrated introduction to simplicial sets](https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.4221) is a marvelous introduction for beginners. For more in-depth references, there are May's [Simplicial Objects in Algebraic Topology](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/BOOKS/Simp.djvu), and [Simplicial Homotopy Theory](http://dodo.pdmi.ras.ru/%7Etopology/books/goerss-jardine.pdf) by Goerss–Jardine.

*Model Categories.* Good references for model category theory include:

- Sections 2.1–2.3 of [Higher Categories and Homotopical Algebra](http://www.mathematik.uni-regensburg.de/cisinski/CatLR.pdf) (Cisinski);
- [Introduction to Homotopy Theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Introduction+to+Homotopy+Theory) (nLab);
- [Categorical Homotopy Theory](http://www.math.jhu.edu/%7Eeriehl/cathtpy.pdf) (Riehl);
- [Model Categories](https://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/otherpapers/hovey-model-cats.pdf) (Hovey);
- Part 4 of [More Concise Algebraic Topology](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/TEAK/KateBookFinal.pdf) (May);

**4. ($\infty$-Categories, finally)**
It is hard to capture in a precise way the idea of an $\infty$-category as a set of objects, together with a set of morphisms, a set of $2$-morphisms, and so on. There are two ways of approaching this difficulty, one traditional, the other very recent.

*Via Quasicategories.* The traditional one is to use *models* for $\infty$-categories. One such model is given by a special kind of simplicial set called a *quasicategory*. This is the approach developed by Joyal and Lurie. For learning the theory of quasicategories, there are:

- [A Short Course on $\infty$-Categories](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1007.2925.pdf) (Groth);
- [Kerodon](https://kerodon.net/) (Lurie; a (WIP) textbook);
- [Higher Categories and Homotopical Algebra](http://www.mathematik.uni-regensburg.de/cisinski/CatLR.pdf) (Cisinski);
- [Higher Topos Theory](http://www.math.harvard.edu/%7Elurie/papers/HTT.pdf) (Lurie; this is best used as a reference, not as a textbook).

*Via $\infty$-Cosmoi.* The second one is the model-independent approach of Riehl and Verity (which is currently being developed). Instead of axiomatizing what $\infty$-categories are via models, Riehl–Verity axiomatize the mathematical object in which $\infty$-categories live, and call it an *$\infty$-cosmos*.

When working with an specific model for $\infty$-categories, one is often lead to complicated arguments involving its combinatorics. On the other hand, in Riehl–Verity's framework, it is possible to prove statements about $\infty$-categories in a much simpler, *model-independent*, way

Riehl and Verity are currently compiling their work in a textbook, called [Elements of $\infty$-Category Theory](http://www.math.jhu.edu/%7Eeriehl/elements.pdf).

---

***Extra References***

**$\infty$-Categories**

- [Notes on $\infty$-categories](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.06271.pdf) (Hinich);
- [Notes on $\infty$-categories](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Esmorel/notes.pdf) (Morel, in French);
- [Homotopy Theory of Higher Categories: From Segal Categories to $n$-Categories and Beyond](https://www.cambridge.org/br/academic/subjects/mathematics/geometry-and-topology/homotopy-theory-higher-categories-segal-categories-ini-categories-and-beyond?format=HB) (Simpson);
- [The Homotopy Theory of $(\infty,1)$-Categories](https://www.cambridge.org/br/academic/subjects/mathematics/logic-categories-and-sets/homotopy-theory-1-categories?format=PB) (Bergner).

**Background on model categories and simplicial sets**

- [Notes on Homotopical Algebra](http://zll22.user.srcf.net/writing/homotopical-algebra/2015-09-19-Main.pdf) (Low);
- [Homotopy Limit Functors on Model Categories and Homotopical Categories](https://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/otherpapers/dhks.pdf) (Dwyer et al.);
- [Model Categories and Their Localizations](https://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/otherpapers/pshmain.pdf) (Hirschhorn);

---

**Edit:** Here are some extra (extra) references, in the (way far from optimal) format of a directory tree.

(P.S. Please take the above attempt at a guide with a big grain of salt; there's a lot missing from it!)

```
├── Complete Segal Spaces
│   ├── [BC, 10 Pages] Equivariant Complete Segal Spaces.pdf
│   ├── [Brito, 26 Pages] Segal Objects and the Grothendieck Construction.pdf
│   ├── [Rasekh, 17 Pages] A Model for the Higher Category of Higher Categories.pdf
│   ├── [Rasekh, 44 Pages] Complete Segal Objects.pdf
│   ├── [Rasekh, 478 Pages] A Theory of Elementary Higher Toposes.pdf
│   ├── [Rasekh, 61 Pages] Introduction to Complete Segal Spaces.pdf
│   ├── [Rasekh, 75 Pages] Yoneda Lemma for Simplicial Spaces.pdf
│   ├── [Rasekh, 81 Pages] Cartesian Fibrations and Representability.pdf
│   ├── [Stenzel, 21 Pages] Univalence and Completeness of Segal Objects.pdf
│   └── [Stenzel, 26 Pages] Bousfield-Segal Spaces.pdf
├── Elementary ∞-Topoi
│   ├── [Rasekh, 10 Pages] Yoneda Lemma for Elementary Higher Toposes.pdf
│   ├── [Rasekh, 30 Pages] Filter Quotients and Non-Presentable (∞,1)-Toposes.pdf
│   ├── [Rasekh, 40 Pages] A Theory of Elementary Higher Toposes.pdf
│   ├── [Rasekh, 51 Pages] Every Elementary Higher Topos Has a Natural Number Object.pdf
│   └── [Rasekh, 84 Pages] An Elementary Approach to Truncations.pdf
├── Enriched (∞,1)-Categories
│   ├── [AMR, 68 Pages] Factorization Homology of Enriched ∞-Categories.pdf
│   ├── [GH, 100 Pages] Enriched ∞-Categories via Non-Symmetric ∞-Operads.pdf
│   ├── [Haugseng, 29 Pages] Bimodules and Natural Transformations for Enriched ∞-Categories.pdf
│   └── [Haugseng, 52 Pages] Rectification of Enriched Infinity-Categories.pdf
├── General References
│   ├── [AL, 26 Pages] Exponentiable Higher Toposes.pdf
│   ├── [Arctaedius, 38 Pages] Grothendieck's Homotopy Hypothesis and the Homotopy Theory of Homotopy Theories.pdf
│   ├── [Bergner, 13 Pages] A Survey of (∞, 1)-Categories.pdf
│   ├── [Bergner, 287 Pages] The Homotopy Theory of (∞,1)-Categories.pdf
│   ├── [Bergner, 29 Pages] A Survey of Models for (∞,n)-Categories.pdf
│   ├── [Bergner, 39 Pages] Workshop on the Homotopy Theory of Homotopy Theories.pdf
│   ├── [Camarena, 45 Pages] A Whirlwind Tour of the World of (∞,1)-Categories.pdf
│   ├── [Clough, 35 Pages] An Outline of the Theory of (∞,1)-Categories.pdf
│   ├── [Dorn, 99 Pages] Basic concepts in homotopy theory.pdf
│   ├── [HF, 148 Pages] The Homotopy Theory of (∞,1)-Categories.pdf
│   ├── [Mazel-Gee, 26 Pages] The Zen of ∞-Categories.pdf
│   ├── [Porter, 37 Pages] -categories, -groupoids, Segal categories and quasicategories.pdf
│   ├── [Porter, 54 Pages] Spaces as ∞-groupoids.pdf
│   ├── [Porter, 759 Pages] The Crossed Menagerie.pdf
│   ├── [Schommer-Pries, 65 Pages] Dualizability in Low-Dimensional Higher Category Theory.pdf
│   └── [Simpson, 653 Pages] Homotopy Theory of Higher Categories.pdf
├── Model (∞,1)-Categories
│   ├── [LM, 21 Pages] From Fractions to Complete Segal Spaces.pdf
│   ├── [Mazel-Gee, 16 Pages] A User's Guide to Co⧸Cartesian Fibrations.pdf
│   ├── [Mazel-Gee, 20 Pages] Quillen Adjunctions Induce Adjunctions of Quasicategories.pdf
│   ├── [Mazel-Gee, 26 Pages] The Universality of the Rezk Nerve.pdf
│   ├── [Mazel-Gee, 29 Pages] Model ∞-Categories II: Quillen Adjunctions.pdf
│   ├── [Mazel-Gee, 34 Pages] Model ∞-Categories III: The Fundamental Theorem.pdf
│   ├── [Mazel-Gee, 41 Pages] All About the Grothendieck Construction.pdf
│   ├── [Mazel-Gee, 43 Pages] Hammocks and Fractions in Relative ∞-Categories.pdf
│   ├── [Mazel-Gee, 528 Slides] Goerss–Hopkins obstruction theory for ∞-Categories.pdf
│   ├── [Mazel-Gee, 545 Pages] Goerss–Hopkins obstruction theory via model ∞-categories.pdf
│   ├── [Mazel-Gee, 54 Pages] Goerss–Hopkins Obstruction Theory for ∞-Categories.pdf
│   ├── [Mazel-Gee, 66 Pages] Model ∞-Categories I: Some Pleasant Properties of the ∞-Category of Simplicial Spaces.pdf
│   └── [Mazel-Gee, 6 Pages] _∞ Automorphisms of Motivic Morava E-Theories.pdf
├── Other Models
│   ├── Batanin ∞-Categories
│   │   └── [Ara, 168 Pages] Sur les ∞-groupoïdes de Grothendieck et une variante ∞-catégorique.pdf
│   ├── Grothendieck–Maltsiniotis ∞-Categories
│   │   ├── [AL, 65 Pages] The Folk Model Category Structure on Strict ω-Categories Is Monoidal.pdf
│   │   ├── [AM, 123 Pages] A Quillen's Theorem A for Strict ∞-Categories II: The ∞-Categorical Proof.pdf
│   │   ├── [AM, 227 Pages] Join and Slices for Strict ∞-Categories.pdf
│   │   ├── [AM, 25 Pages] The Brown–Golasinski Model Structure on Strict ∞-Groupoids Revisited.pdf
│   │   ├── [AM, 42 Pages] Comparison of the n-Categorical Nerves.pdf
│   │   ├── [AM, 51 Pages] A Quillen's Theorem A for Strict ∞-Categories I: The Simplicial Proof.pdf
│   │   ├── [AM, 68 Pages] The Homotopy Type of the ∞-Category Associated to a Simplicial Complex.pdf
│   │   ├── [AM, 92 Pages] Towards a Thomason Model Structure on the Category of Strict n-Categories.pdf
│   │   ├── [Ara, 22 Pages] On Homotopy Types Modelized by Strict ∞-Groupoids.pdf
│   │   ├── [Ara, 22 Pages] Strict ∞-Groupoids Are Grothendieck ∞-Groupoids.pdf
│   │   ├── [Ara, 33 Pages] A Quillen Theorem B for Strict ∞-Categories.pdf
│   │   ├── [Ara, 41 Pages] The Groupoidal Analogue Θ to Joyal's Category Θ Is a Test Category.pdf
│   │   └── [Ara, 58 Pages] On the Homotopy Theory of Grothendieck ∞-Groupoids.pdf
│   ├── Miscellany
│   │   ├── [CL, 61 Pages] Weak ∞-Categories via Terminal Coalgebras.pdf
│   │   ├── [Harpaz, 69 Pages] Quasi-Unital ∞-Categories.pdf
│   │   ├── [LM, 68 Pages] Linear Quasi-Categories as Templicial Modules.pdf
│   │   └── [Nikolaus, 26 Pages] Algebraic Models for Higher Categories.pdf
│   ├── Relative Categories
│   │   ├── [BK, 19 Pages] n-Relative Categories.pdf
│   │   ├── [BK, 27 Pages] Relative Categories: Another Model for the Homotopy Theory of Homotopy Theories.pdf
│   │   ├── [BK, 3 Pages] A Thomason-Like Quillen Equivalence Between Quasi-Categories and Relative Categories.pdf
│   │   ├── [BK, 5 Pages] In the Category of Relative Categories the Rezk Equivalences Are Exactly the DK-equivalences.pdf
│   │   └── [Meier, 21 Pages] Fibration Categories Are Fibrant Relative Categories.pdf
│   └── Topological Categories
│       ├── [Amrani, 22 Pages] A Model Structure on the Category of Topological Categories.pdf
│       └── [Lindberg, 70 Pages] Equivariant Sheaves on Topological Categories.pdf
├── Parametrised (∞,1)-Categories
│   ├── [BDGNS, 11 Pages] Parametrized Higher Category Theory and Higher Algebra: A General Introduction.pdf
│   ├── [BDGNS, 23 Pages] Parametrized Higher Category Theory and Higher Algebra: Exposé I -- Elements of Parametrized Higher Category Theory.pdf
│   ├── [Nardin, 21 Pages] Parametrized Higher Category Theory and Higher Algebra: Exposé IV -- Stability With Respect to an Orbital ∞-Category.pdf
│   ├── [Shah, 81 Pages] Parametrized Higher Category Theory and Higher Algebra: Exposé II - Indexed Homotopy Limits and Colimits.pdf
│   └── [Shah, 86 Slides] Parametrized Higher Category Theory.pdf
├── Quasicategories
│   ├── [AL, 26 Pages] Exponentiable Higher Toposes.pdf
│   ├── [Beardsley, 78 Pages] Coalgebraic Structure and Intermediate Hopf–Galois Extensions of Thom Spectra in Quasicategories.pdf
│   ├── [Berman, 13 Pages] On Lax Limits in ∞-Categories.pdf
│   ├── [BG, 11 Pages] On the Fibrewise Effective Burnside ∞-Category.pdf
│   ├── [BM, 30 Pages] Spectral Sequences in (∞,1)-Categories.pdf
│   ├── [BS, 18 Pages] Fibrations in ∞-Category Theory.pdf
│   ├── [BV, 267 Pages] Homotopy Invariant Algebraic Structures On Topological Spaces.djvu
│   ├── [Campbell, 3 Pages] A Counterexample in Quasi-Category Theory.pdf
│   ├── [Cisinski, 204 Pages] Algèbre Homotopique et Catégories Supérieures.pdf
│   ├── [Cisinski, 446 Pages] Higher Categories and Homotopical Algebra.pdf
│   ├── [Cisisnki, 57 Pages] Catégories Supérieures et Théorie des Topos.pdf
│   ├── [DS, 46 Pages] Mapping Spaces in Quasi-Categories.pdf
│   ├── [Fiore, 24 Pages] Quasicategorical Adjunctions.pdf
│   ├── [GR, 11 Pages] Simplified HTT 4.3.2.15.pdf
│   ├── [GR, 85 Pages] Some Higher Algebra.pdf
│   ├── [Gregoric, 21 Pages] Gregoric Blitzkrieg.pdf
│   ├── [Groth, 77 Pages] A Short Course on ∞-Categories.pdf
│   ├── [Harpaz, 116 Pages] Little Cube Algebras and Factorisation Homology.pdf
│   ├── [Harpaz, 7 Pages] Limits, colimits and adjunctions in ∞-categories.pdf
│   ├── [Haugseng, 12 Pages] On (Co)ends in ∞-Categories.pdf
│   ├── [Haugseng, 28 Pages] A Fibrational Mate Correspondence for ∞-Categories.pdf
│   ├── [Haugseng, 87 Pages] Introduction to ∞-Categories.pdf
│   ├── [HH, 684 Pages] Higher Categories I & II
│   │   ├── 0    [Hebestreit, 13 Pages] A Fairytale.pdf
│   │   ├── 10  [Hebestreit, 11 Pages] Fat and Thin Slices.pdf
│   │   ├── 11  [Hebestreit, 43 Pages] Cartesian Fibrations.pdf
│   │   ├── 12  [Hebestreit, 121 Pages] Straightening and Unstraightening.pdf
│   │   ├── 12' [HH, 53 Pages] Straightening and Unstraightening (Heuts's Notes).pdf
│   │   ├── 13  [Hebestreit, 14 Pages] Homotopy Colimits.pdf
│   │   ├── 14  [Hebestreit, 10 Pages] Simplicial Model Categories.pdf
│   │   ├── 15  [Hebestreit, 35 Pages] Yoneda's Lemma, Adjunctions and (Co)Limits.pdf
│   │   ├── 1    [Hebestreit, 37 Pages] Categories.pdf
│   │   ├── 2    [Hebestreit, 25 Pages] Simplicial Sets.pdf
│   │   ├── 3    [Hebestreit, 10 Pages] Quasicategories.pdf
│   │   ├── 4    [Hebestreit, 53 Pages] Simplicial Categories.pdf
│   │   ├── 5    [Hebestreit, 38 Pages] Simplicial Homotopy Theory.pdf
│   │   ├── 6    [Hebestreit, 57 Pages] Quasicategories and Anima.pdf
│   │   ├── 7    [Hebestreit, 67 Pages] Equivalences, Equivalences, Equivalences.pdf
│   │   ├── 8    [Hebestreit, 9 Pages] A Fairytale.pdf
│   │   └── 9    [Hebestreit, 88 Pages] Localisations and Model Categories.pdf
│   ├── [Hinich, 111 Pages] Lectures on ∞-Categories.pdf
│   ├── [Joyal, 244 Pages] Notes on Quasi-Categories.pdf
│   ├── [Joyal, 350 Pages] The Theory of Quasi-Categories and its Applications II.pdf
│   ├── [Joyal, 479 Pages] The Theory of Quasi-Categories.pdf
│   ├── [Lejay, 139 Pages] Algèbres à Factorisation et Topos Supérieurs Exponentiables.pdf
│   ├── [Lurie, 60 Pages] On ∞-Topoi.pdf
│   ├── [Lurie, 841 Pages] Kerodon.pdf
│   ├── [Lurie, 949 Pages] Higher Topos Theory.pdf
│   ├── [Lysenko, 208 Pages] Lysenko's comments to Gaitsgory–Rozenblyum.pdf
│   ├── [Morel, 118 Pages] ∞-Categories.pdf
│   ├── [Nguyen, 94 Pages] Theorems in Higher Category Theory and Applications.pdf
│   ├── [NRS, 21 Pages] Adjoint Functor Theorems for ∞-Categories.pdf
│   ├── [Porta, 100 Pages] Derived formal moduli problems.pdf
│   ├── [Rezk, 11 Pages] Degenerate Edges of Cartesian Fibrations are Cartesian Edges.pdf
│   ├── [Rezk, 175 Pages] Stuff About Quasicategories.pdf
│   ├── [Rezk, 50 Pages] Toposes and homotopy toposes.pdf
│   ├── [Riehl, 20 Pages] Quasi-Categories as (∞,1)-Categories.pdf
│   ├── [Riehl, 292 Pages] Categorical homotopy theory.pdf
│   ├── [Riehl, 9 Pages] Associativity Data in an (∞,1)-Category.pdf
│   ├── [Rovelli, 38 Pages] Weighted Limits in an (∞,1)-Category.pdf
│   ├── [RS, 151 Pages] Notes on Higher Categories.pdf
│   ├── [RV, 33 Pages] Completeness Results for Quasi-Categories of Algebras, Homotopy Limits, and Related General Constructions.pdf
│   ├── [Stevenson, 12 Pages] Stability for Inner Fibrations Revisited.pdf
│   ├── [Tanaka, 14 Pages] Functors (Between ∞-Categories) That Aren't Strictly Unital.pdf
│   ├── [Thanh, 46 Pages] Quasicategories.pdf
│   ├── [Wong, 83 Pages] The Grothendieck construction in enriched, internal and ∞-Category Theory.pdf
│   ├── [Zsámboki, 31 Pages] A summary of higher topos theory.pdf
│   └── [無, 5 Pages] HTT ToC.pdf
├── Simplicial Categories
│   ├── [Bergner, 16 Pages] A model category structure on the category of simplicial categories.pdf
│   ├── [Bergner, 22 Pages] Complete Segal Spaces Arising From Simplicial Categories.pdf
│   ├── [Bergner, 40 Pages] Three models for the homotopy theory of homotopy theories.pdf
│   ├── [Cordier, 21 Pages] Sur la notion de diagramme homotopiquement cohérent.pdf
│   ├── [CP, 26 Pages] Vogt's Theorem on Categories of Homotopy Coherent Diagrams.pdf
│   ├── [CP, 54 Pages] Homotopy Coherent Category Theory.pdf
│   ├── [DS, 29 Pages] Rigidification of Quasi-Categories.pdf
│   ├── [DS, 64 Pages] Mapping Spaces in Quasi-Categories.pdf
│   ├── [Hinich, 23 Pages] Homotopy Coherent Nerve in Deformation Theory.pdf
│   ├── [HK, 14 Pages] Mapping Spaces in Homotopy Coherent Nerves.pdf
│   ├── [Joyal, 66 Pages] Quasi-Categories vs Simplicial Categories.pdf
│   ├── [Riehl, 16 Pages] On the Structure of Simplicial Categories Associated to Quasi-Categories.pdf
│   ├── [Riehl, 26 Pages] Homotopy Coherent Structures.pdf
│   ├── [Riehl, 292 Pages] Categorical Homotopy Theory.pdf
│   └── [Riehl, 7 Pages] Understanding the Homotopy Coherent Nerve.pdf
├── Unicity
│   ├── [Bergner, 16 Pages] Equivalence of Models for Equivariant (∞,1)-Categories.pdf
│   ├── [BS, 47 Pages] On the Unicity of the Homotopy Theory of Higher Categories.pdf
│   ├── [JT, 49 Pages] Quasi-Categories vs Segal Spaces.pdf
│   ├── [Riehl, 58 Pages] Seminar Notes on the Barwick–Schommer–Pries Unicity Theorem.pdf
│   └── [Toën, 32 Pages] Vers une axiomatisation de la théorie des catégories supérieures.pdf
└── Un⧸Straightening
    ├── [AF, 89 Pages] Fibrations of ∞-Categories.pdf
    ├── [BGN, 19 Pages] Dualizing Cartesian and Cocartesian Fibrations.pdf
    ├── [BS, 18 Pages] Fibrations in ∞-Category Theory.pdf
    ├── [Campbell, 31 Slides] A modular proof of the straightening theorem.pdf
    ├── [GHN, 42 Pages] Lax Colimits and Free Fibrations in ∞-Categories.pdf
    ├── [GR, 85 Pages] Some Higher Algebra.pdf
    ├── [Hebestreit, 121 Pages] Straightening and Unstraightening.pdf
    ├── [HH, 53 Pages] Straightening and Unstraightening (Heuts's Notes).pdf
    ├── [HM, 17 Pages] Left Fibrations and Homotopy Colimits II.pdf
    ├── [HM, 27 Pages] Left Fibrations and Homotopy Colimits.pdf
    ├── [Mazel-Gee, 16 Pages] A User's Guide to (Co)Cartesian Fibrations.pdf
    ├── [Mazel-Gee, 41 Pages] All About the Grothendieck Construction.pdf
    ├── [Noel, 1 Page] Cartesian Model Structure.pdf
    ├── [PK, 43 Pages] Straightening and Unstraightening.pdf
    ├── [Richardson, 14 Pages] Mapping Spaces and Straightening-Unstraightening.pdf
    ├── [Stevenson, 41 Pages] Model Structures for Correspondences and Bifibrations.pdf
    ├── [Stevenson, 49 Pages] Covariant Model Structures and Simplicial Localization.pdf
    └── [Wong, 83 Pages] The Grothendieck Constructionin Enriched, Internal and ∞-Category Theory.pdf
```